# open google chrome in fullscreen by default

Tags: google-chrome, web, fullscreen, kiosk

I have a website that I always need to open in full screen and ban the exit from the full screen. Also, you need to hide the cross button in the circle that goes out of the full screen. I tried to make a kiosk in the google app builder but it keeps the buttons open - it's not good. Please, help))

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-open-the-chrome-in-F11-mode-by-default
 - dont work

Comment: Locking down a machine to a browser turns out to be a very complicated thing. There are a bunch of commercial kiosk solutions that provide a full screen browser that is already locked down (full disclosure: I work at a company that makes one of them). You just worry about writing the web content for the kiosk.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Can I buy your work?

Comment: Sorry - I just found your question. If you are still interested in learning more about our software, trying searching google for KioWare.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1
Place your Chrome browser into fullscreen mode by clicking "View" in the Chrome toolbar and selecting "Enter Presentation Mode," or by pressing command-shift-F on your keyboard.

Step 2
Place your mouse at the top of the screen to reveal the hidden tabs and menus, and click the Chrome menu button to the right of the address bar. It looks like three horizontal lines.

Step 3
Scroll down and select "Settings."

Press the radio buttons next to "Continue where I left off" and under the "On Startup" heading. You do not have to press any save buttons to confirm your choice, simply continue browsing.

Tip
To exit Chrome in fullscreen mode, which eliminates access to the close button, press Command-q on your keyboard.